# How to triger a button based on the selected option in menu in tkinkter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, tkinter.optionmenu

I have a list and 3 paths. Every path refers to an application that runs specifically for that country.

```
country = ['Spain', 'United Kingdom', 'Malaysia']

path_spain = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\spain_software.py"
path_uk = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\uk_software.py"
path_malaysia = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\malaysia_software.py"
```

The `Run button` I created needs to trigger one of those 3 applications based on the country I select in the `OptionMenu`. So If I select `Malaysia` I want the `Run button` to run the application in the `path_malaysia`. I'm struggling to fix this. Preferably I would also like the `Run button` to change to `Run application Malaysia` if I click `Malaysia` in the `OptionMenu` for example.

**This is my code:**

```
import os
from tkinter import *
       
window = Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script") #Create window
window.geometry('550x300') #geo of the window

def run():
    os.system('python path_spain') 

#The run button (this button runs some other software)
run_button = Button(window, text="Run application.....", bg="blue", fg="white",command=run)
run_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

#These are the option menus
dd_country = StringVar(window)
dd_country.set(country [0]) #the first value
w = OptionMenu(window, dd_country, *country)
w.grid(row=0,column=1)

#These are the titles
l1 = Label(window,  text='Select Country', width=15 )  
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

mainloop()
```

Right now it only runs for Spain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
from tkinter import *

owner = ['Spain', 'United Kingdom', 'Malaysia']

path_spain = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\spain_software.py"
path_uk = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\uk_software.py"
path_malaysia = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\malaysia_software.py"

window = Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script")  # Create window
window.geometry('550x300')  # geo of the window


def run():
    if dd_owner.get() == "Spain":
        print("spain")
        # os.system('python path_spain')
    elif dd_owner.get() == "United Kingdom":
        os.system('python path_uk')

    elif dd_owner.get() == "Malaysia":
        os.system('python path_malaysia')


def update_button(_):
    run_button.config(text="Run application {}".format(dd_owner.get()))


# The run button (this button runs some other software)


# These are the option menus
dd_owner = StringVar(window)
dd_owner.set(owner[0])  # the first value
w = OptionMenu(window, dd_owner, *owner, command=update_button)
# w.config()
w.grid(row=0, column=1)

run_button = Button(window, text="Run application {}".format(dd_owner.get()), bg="blue", fg="white",command=run)
run_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

# These are the titles
l1 = Label(window, text='Select Owner', width=15)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: You should provide some explanation.

Comment: Oke and what about the changing text in the button based on the selection?

Comment: The problem was is in run function of the code. he was asking user his choice but was not using that. he was only running spain code but now when I edited I used if user choice is spain then run spain if uk then run uk like this

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
def run():
    if dd_owner.get() == "Spain":
        os.system(f'python "{path_spain}"') #=== Run the file by formatting the path into the string
    elif dd_owner.get() == "United Kingdom":
        os.system(f'python "{path_uk}"')  #=== Run the file by formatting the path into the string
    
    elif dd_owner.get() == "Malaysia":
        os.system(f'python "{path_malaysia}"')  #=== Run the file by formatting the path into the string
```

Also to change the button text:

```
def change_text(*args):
    if dd_owner.get() == "Spain":
        
        run_button.config(text="Run Application Spain") #== Configure button
    elif dd_owner.get() == "United Kingdom":
        
        run_button.config(text="Run Application United Kingdom") #== Configure button
    elif dd_owner.get() == "Malaysia":
        
        run_button.config(text="Run Application Malaysia") #== Configure button
```

Also remember to add this code:

```
dd_owner.trace("w",change_text) #=== Trace the stringVar for changes.
```

Change the button code.

Place it below `dd_owner.set(owner[0])  # the first value`

In all, the code is as follows:

```
import os
from tkinter import *

owner = ['Spain', 'United Kingdom', 'Malaysia']

path_spain = "C:/data/FF/Desktop/PythonFolder/spain_software.py"
path_uk = "C:/data/FF/Desktop/PythonFolder/uk_software.py"
path_malaysia = "C:/data/FF/Desktop/PythonFolder/malaysia_software.py"

window = Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script")  # Create window
window.geometry('550x300')  # geo of the window


def run():
    if dd_owner.get() == "Spain":
        os.system(f'python "{path_spain}"')
        run_button.config(text="Run Application Spain")
    elif dd_owner.get() == "United Kingdom":
        os.system(f'python "{path_uk}"')
        run_button.config(text="Run Application United Kingdom")
    elif dd_owner.get() == "Malaysia":
        os.system(f'python "{path_malaysia}"')
        run_button.config(text="Run Application Malaysia")

def change_text(*args):
    if dd_owner.get() == "Spain":
        
        run_button.config(text="Run Application Spain")
    elif dd_owner.get() == "United Kingdom":
        
        run_button.config(text="Run Application United Kingdom")
    elif dd_owner.get() == "Malaysia":
        
        run_button.config(text="Run Application Malaysia")

# The run button (this button runs some other software)
dd_owner = StringVar(window)
dd_owner.set(owner[0])  # the first value

run_button = Button(window, text=f"Run application {dd_owner.get()}", bg="blue", fg="white", command=run)
run_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

# These are the option menus
w = OptionMenu(window, dd_owner, *owner)
dd_owner.trace("w",change_text)
w.grid(row=0, column=1)

# These are the titles
l1 = Label(window, text='Select Owner', width=15)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I put it in double quotation marks because it can cause some problems if python is trying to fetch the file from a folder which has spaces in its name: like ```New Folder```

Comment: Thank you. Could we continue the discussion in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232816/discussion

Comment: I have joined @TangerCity